# Get bin edges from a histogram by index of the bin

Tags: matlab, histogram, binning, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix `m` and plot a histogram of the third column. I search for the peak in the first 100 bins and get the frequency as `a` and the index of the bin as `b`. Now I need the edges of the bin with index `b`. How can I get them?

```
nbins = 1000; 
histo = histogram(m(:,3),nbins,'Orientation','horizontal'); 
[a,b] = max(histo.Values(1:100))
```

Comment: Use the outputs of `histcounts`, or `histo.BinEdges`.

Comment: Thank you! :D 
When I write `c = histo.BinEdges(b)` I get one value back. Is this the left or the right binEdge or in my case the lower or upper Edge?

Comment: Don't ask - try it yourself... :) (hint: the `BinEdges` vector is longer by 1 than `Values`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two easy ways to do this:

```
function q41505566
m = randn(10000,5);
nBins = 1000;

% Option 1: using histcounts:
[N,E] = histcounts(m(:,3),nBins);
disp(E(find(N(1:100) == max(N(1:100)),1,'first')+[0 1])); % find() returns the left bin edge

% Option 2: using BinEdges:
histo = histogram(m(:,3),nBins,'Orientation','horizontal'); 
[a,b] = max(histo.Values(1:100));
disp(histo.BinEdges(b:b+1));
```

If you need an explanation for the "tricks" - please say so.